# How can I find classes with underscores in them using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, element

As the question implies I'm scraping a webpage that has a class name with an underscore in it, I'm unable to locate it. The element is as follows

```
<span class="s-item__time-left">30m</span> == $0
```

I've tried finding it by class name

```
time = driver.find_elements_class_name("s-item__time-left")
```

This just returns nothing, so I moved onto css selectors

```
time = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("s-item__time-left")
```

I tried a variety of the above, with one "." replaceing the 2 underscores and with 2 dots replacing the underscores. Both of these returned nothing as well.

There's no unique ID I can use, they vary constantly, all of the parent classes also use multiple underscores so I can't path to it hoping through the child elements.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `css selector` was wrong. it should be `.classname`

Try now.

```
time =driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".s-item__time-left")
print(time.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPATH: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="s-item__time-left"]')`